# How to handle a function with many dependencies

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have a method that depends on many other classes like this

```
public function getProfileData(
    ProfilesService $profile_service, 
    ContactInfoService $contact_info_service, 
    CoursesService $courses_service,
    InterestsService $interests_service,
    LanguagesService $languages_service,
    PersonalInfoService $personal_info_service,
    ProjectsService $projects_service,
    SkillsService $skills_service,
    AwardsService $awards_service,
    EducationsService $education_service,
    ExperiencesService $experiences_service,
    TargetJobsService $target_jobs_service,
    ProfileHiddenSectionsService $hidden_sections_service) { }
```

I read about dependency injection and I know that if you exceed 6-10 dependencies it leads you to a code smell.

But this `getProfileData()` method really need all of these dependencies so what is the best practice to solve this problem ?!

Comment: The reason it is seen as a code smell when a dependent has that many dependencies is because it would appear as though the dependent is probably doing too much, in violation of the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)

Comment: _method **really need all of these dependencies** so what is the best practice to solve this problem_ - then what is the problem?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm already following the (SRP) principle in my code but this method specifically needs all of this dependencies, so is that right or is there is another way to handle this ?!

Comment: @Fabio I read a lot of articles about dependency injection and most of them agreed that more than 6-10 dependencies consider as code smell !!! so are they right or is there another way ?!

Comment: It is very unlikely that a method (or class) that requires 13!! dependencies has one single responsibility according to the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @Steven, unless responsibility is to collect data from all dependencies and return combined result. So I will have one place to change when logic of how to combine data will changes later.

Comment: @MohamedEmad, yes articles mention about this and usually it is 2-3 dependencies. But do you have problems with this class?

Comment: @MohamedEmad, check how those dependencies used in your class. Is there dependencies which used by other dependencies? Is there dependencies which used by only one dependency, if so they can be a candidates for combining them into one dependency class.

Comment: @Fabio, the reason Constructor over-injection (or this variant 'method over-injection') is called a _code smell_, rather than an _anti-pattern_ is because it is possible that the class or method in question still has one responsibility. However, the likeliness that the class/method becomes a maintenance problem (and has a SRP violation) increases with every extra dependency.

Comment: @Steven, totally agree. That what I tried to ask OP about, is there a possible risk. Very important is how those dependencies are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code smell you are experiencing is called [Constructor over-injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/) (and this particular variation is *Method over-injection*). As @Nkosi said in the comments, the source of this is a [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation.

How to solve this problem, however, depends pretty much on the situation. [Chapter 6](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-second-edition-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6) from the book [Dependency Injection: Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) actually contains a very elaborate description of your options. In short, among other things, you can use the following refactorings:

- [Facade Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/)
- Introduce [Domain Events](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html)
- Hide similar components behind a [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)
- Extract [cross-cutting concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) using [Decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)